# Paginate on Mongodb '$group' Aggregated Results

Tags: mongodb

I am creating an API to return the results grouped using Status.

In MongoDB I have the records containing the following fields:

```
{
  id: Integer,
  Status: String,
  Subject: String,
  Date: Date
}
```

I am using the following aggregate query to fetch results grouped based on "Status".

```
db.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$Status',
            count: { $sum: 1 },
            tickets: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
        }
    }
])
```

I need to show only 10 records in each group at a time. 
I am using MongoDB 3.6

How can I implement pagination on the grouped results returned by that aggregate Query?

Answer (score 0):

> **skip(n)** will skip **n** documents from the cursor while **limit(n)** will cap
>   the number of documents to be returned from the cursor. Thus
>   combination of two naturally paginates the response.

```
//Get count from the query params
let limit = parseInt(req.query.count) || 10; 

//Get pageNumber from the query params
let pageNumber = parseInt(req.query.pageNumber) || 1;

if (pageNumber < 1 || limit < 1) res.json([]); // Return empty

let skip = (pageNumber - 1) * limit;

let searchConditions = [ { $group: { _id: '$Status', count: { $sum: 1 }, tickets: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } } ];

db.aggregate(searchConditions)
  .skip(skip)
  .limit(limit)
```

Comment: Thanks for Answering. But it is not paginating the grouped results.
After aggregate query output will be like:

**[{_id:"Open",count:123,tickets:[ {} ] },{_id:"Close",count:623,tickets:[ {} ] } ]**

Tickets array in each group will contain all tickets of that group. I want to paginate here in such a way that tickets array in each group contain only 10 tickets at a time without affecting the count.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's not possible to do this at the time of push.

If the below one gets incorrect try with

```
    Query when pagination button click with skip and limit
```

Try this one. Don't know whether this will help you.
and I donno whether this is correct method.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$Status',
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        tickets: { $push: '$$ROOT' }
    }
},
{
    $addFields:{
        tickets:{ $slice: [ "$tickets", 2,3] }
        }
}
])
```

2,3 are position and number of data that returns respectively.
Just try.
I will try for another method without slice.

Comment: Slicing will work after $group stage right?
Is it possible to do this within $group stage itself?

Comment: Actually `slice` is not a method for `skip` and `limit` . Here `slice `used to number of items of an array that a query returns.

Comment: I have like 1 Million records. For every next page request, it would scan through all 1 Million records and then only it will apply slice right?

Comment: I think It's not possible to do this at the time of push. We can search for it.

Comment: Yes you are right. I need pagination at this($group) stage itself. Thanks for your support.

Comment: If it is harder, then u can call a query for pagination with skip and limit. `For each pagination click, call a db call with proper skip and limit`. I think it will help you. Don't get complex with slice. I will try ma best for a proper query.

Comment: I have some doubt. Why there is a need of `group` and `limit`. Go with direct `match`, `skip`  and  `limit`

Comment: Throughout my searches, I couldn't see a proper query in mongodb to do this.
I am using the count of each group for plotting graphs in front end. Also on clciking the portion of graph representing a  status like open will reveal records having status open.  This can't achieved using match. I need $group for grouping the records.

Comment: Yup. You are right. You can go for a separate query for for pagination. For speedup `indexing` can be used. I think `slice` may a little slow your query.

Comment: What do u mean by separate query? Since Http is stateless, we can't store the results and then paginate over subsequent requests.